# how do I concatenate and join an array of strings with a delimiter in powershell?

Tags: arrays, string, powershell, concatenation, pester

PS C:\Users\User\ps-modules> more .\MyStrings.Tests.ps1

```
function slist { "1", "2", "3" }

Describe 'StringTests' {

  It 'literal -join' {
    "1", "2", "3" -join "," | Should -Be "1,2,3"
  }

  It 'literal -join' {
    @("1", "2", "3") -join "," | Should -Be "1,2,3"
  }

  It 'slist returns a list of string' {
    slist | Should -Be @("1", "2", "3")
  }

  It 'slist -join' {
    slist -join "," | Should -Be "1,2,3"
  }

}
```

PS C:\Users\User\ps-modules> pwsh .\MyStrings.Tests.ps1

```
Starting discovery in 1 files.
Discovery found 4 tests in 169ms.
Running tests.
[-] StringTests.slist -join 55ms (53ms|2ms)
 Expected '1,2,3', but got @('1', '2', '3').
 at slist -join "," | Should -Be "1,2,3", C:\Users\User\ps-modules\MyStrings.Tests.ps1:17
 at <ScriptBlock>, C:\Users\User\ps-modules\MyStrings.Tests.ps1:17
Tests completed in 731ms
Tests Passed: 3, Failed: 1, Skipped: 0 NotRun: 0
```

Why is the array treated differently when it comes from a function return vs when it's literally declared?

Answer (score 11):

`-join ','` is interpreted as arguments being passed to your `slist` function, with this slight modification we can see it better:

```
function slist { "1", "2", "3" + $args }
slist -join ","
```

Which outputs:

```
1
2
3
-join
,
```

In this case you would need to use the [grouping operator `( )`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#grouping-operator--), as stated in the doc:

> `(...)` allows you to let output from a *command* participate in an expression.

```
(slist) -join "," -eq '1,2,3' # True
```

As an alternative in **PowerShell 6.2+** you can use [`Join-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/join-string?view=powershell-7.4):

```
slist | Join-String -Separator ','
```